# Como hacer validaciones en datatables?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5, datatables

He averiguado en la pagina oficial de `Data Tables` como hacer validaciones, pero me parece algo muy complejo como para lo que estoy realizando.

La validación que requiero es un poco parecido a como si lo realizara con PHP pero en este caso es en un ciclo for en JS manejando el `Data Tables`.

**EL CODIGO:**

```
 var table_show = $('#table_students').DataTable({
            "language": {                
                            "sProcessing":     "Procesando...",
                            "sLengthMenu":     "Mostrar _MENU_ registros",
                            "sZeroRecords":    "",
                            "sEmptyTable":     "",
                            "sInfo":           "Mostrando registros del _START_ al _END_ de un total de _TOTAL_ registros",
                            "sInfoEmpty":      "Mostrando registros del 0 al 0 de un total de 0 registros",
                            "sInfoFiltered":   "(filtrado de un total de _MAX_ registros)",
                            "sInfoPostFix":    "",
                            "sSearch":         "Consult Students:",
                            "sUrl":            "",
                            "sInfoThousands":  ",",
                            "sLoadingRecords": "Loading..",
                            "oPaginate":
                             {
                                "sFirst":    "Primero",
                                "sLast":     "Último",
                                "sNext":     "Siguiente",
                                "sPrevious": "Anterior"
                            },
                            "oAria":
                             {
                                "sSortAscending":  ": Activar para ordenar la columna de manera ascendente",
                                "sSortDescending": ": Activar para ordenar la columna de manera descendente"

                            }
                        },
                    }); 

    list_data();
        function list_data()
        {       
    $.ajax({
                        url: 'calificaciones_estudiantes',
                        type: 'POST'
                       })
                .done(function(result)
                {
                    var answer= $.parseJSON(result);

                    if(answer.estado == "vacio")
                    {
                        var response = '<div class="alert alert-warning alert-dismissable">'
                        + '<strong>¡Error!</strong>' + ' ' +answer.mensaje + '</div>';
                        $('#alert').html(response);
                    }

                    if(answer)
                    {
                        for (var i = answer.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) 
                        {
                            var rowNode = table_show
                           .row.add([                               
                                        answer[i].nombre_estudiante,
                                        answer[i].fecha_calificacion,
                                        answer[i].area,
                                        answer[i].calificacion
                                    ])
                           .draw()
                           .node();
                        }
                    }
                })
                .fail(function() {
                    console.log("error");
                    });  
            }
```

**LO REQUERIDO:**

Un estudiante puede tener diferentes calificaciones, por lo cual para "no perderme" por que son muchas calificaciones, quisiera validar si **answer[i].calificacion = "bueno"** *entonces que me muestre las letras de color verde por ejemplo, si es malo que me las muestre rojo...*

El problema es que no sabría como hacer esa validación en ese caso. agradezco de antemano si me pueden colaborar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En tu ciclo `for` dentro de la petición `ajax` agregaría un `if` lineal quedando de esta forma:

```
for (var i = answer.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) 
{
  var rowNode = table_show
  .row.add([                               
    answer[i].nombre_estudiante,
    answer[i].fecha_calificacion,
    answer[i].area,
    (answer[i].calificacion == "bueno" ? 
        "<label style='color:green;'>bueno</label>" : 
        "<label style='color:red;'>malo</label>")
  ])
  .draw()
  .node();
}
```

En el caso de que tengas 3 mas datos de los que quieres validar solo hay que anidar los `if` ejemplo:

```
(answer[i].calificacion == "bueno" ? 
  "<label style='color:green;'>bueno</label>" : 
  //segunda validación 
  (answer[i].calificacion == "regular" ? 
    "<label style='color:yellow;'>regular</label>" : 
    "<label style='color:red;'>malo</label>"
  )
)
```

Comment: Hola @ JuankGlezz Que buen aporte, me acabo de dar cuenta de algo y ps obviamente ha sido mi error, como puedo manejarlo si las calificaciones son Bueno,regular y malo?..osea seria 3 validaciones.

Comment: @Daniel he actualizado mi respuesta, es un poco tedioso usar muchas validaciones con `if` lineales ya que son fáciles de perderte

Comment: Listo @JuankGlezz te agradezco, me sirvio mucho tu codigo.